# Deploy existing data on ASP.NET web project from local database in Visual Studio to Azure database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, razor-pages

I've successfully deployed my ASP.NET project to Azure but the database has been deployed with no data, consequently throwing internal server errors due to functionality requiring that data. I can't see the exact error message as I'm unable to disable customErrors on my project (there's no webconfig file on Razor Pages)

I need to update my database on Azure with the data currently stored locally. How do you do this and is this possible?

N.B - I am using EF core with code-first migrations for data access

Answer (score 0):

On the local machine open the "Microsoft server SQL management studio", connect to the local database server and navigate to the appropriate database. Rightclick on the database name and select "Generate scripts...". Select the tables you want to export, then click "next>". On this screen click the "Advanced" button, scroll down to "Types of data to script" and select "Data only". Now you can generate the script and copy that to a connection to the Azure DB, that can be an other query in de Management Studio or in the Azure portal.